# Is there a way to terminate a program during any part of execution?

Tags: ada

For example in c you could say have a condition and if that condition is not met you can return(0); and this would terminate the program.

Is there a way I could do this in Ada?

Comment: In C, `return 0;` (the parentheses aren't necessary) terminates the program only if it's in the `main` function. Otherwise it merely returns from the current function to its caller -- just like the `return` statement in Ada. C's `exit()` function terminates the program (with some caveats if you've registered something via `atexit()`).  You're asking whether Ada has something equivalent to C's `exit()` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ada 83(Only) How to end an entire program which has multiple procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176305/ada-83only-how-to-end-an-entire-program-which-has-multiple-procedures)

Comment: @KeithThompson yea, sorry thats what I meant, i wanted to know what the exit() equivilant in ADA.

Comment: Just to be picky, it's "Ada", not "ADA". (It's not an acronym, it's named after a person.)

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487175/how-to-stop-execution-in-my-program

Comment: As with the duplicate question, one way is simply to raise an exception without a handler, `raise Program_Error;` will do.

Answer (score 0):

In C you should call exit() function;

But investigating your work, i found some information about.

`if some_condition then
      Abort_Task (Current_Task);
   end if;`

[Ada Process Termination Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Program_termination#Ada)

Comment: I did the following Abort_Task(the name of my main procedure); and got the following error "expected private type "Ada.Task_Identification.Task_Id" and "found procedure name instead of function"

Comment: @Newbie: The you need to obtain a `Task_Id` value corresponding to the current task (which is not the same as the currently executing procedure).

Comment: Wait so you are saying I need to obatin a task id for my main procedure(program) and this will terminate it? Also do you know if there is an easy function or something to obtain that task id?

Comment: Ada's tasks are objects, so you need to pass a self-task(object) to terminate the process (?)... im not sure

Comment: Im not too familiar with Ada i just started learning it. I just want to know if there is anyway i can exit the program to terminal with a certain command. For example in C you can use exit().

Comment: @Newbie If you are in the main procedure (the one that runs first when you start the program, after package initializations), just saying `return;` will terminate the program.  Please also see the duplicate questions in Simon's and my comments.  I would avoid using `Abort_Task` to accomplish this.  It's usually the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use GNAT, try `GNAT.OS_Lib.OS_Exit(1);`
this terminates the program with the given exit code.

However, if you want some finalisation try `GNAT.OS_Lib.OS_Abort;`